# CefSharp For WPF Not Displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf, cefsharp

I installed CefSharp in my application through NuGet then initialized it in my app.xaml.cs `OnStartup()` method.  When my application runs I get nothing displayed and no errors.  Switching the view out for another view that doesn't use CefSharp displays as normal.  I just can't seem to get a webpage to render with CefSharp.

**View [QuestHTMLView]**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser Grid.Row="0" Address="https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions" />
</Grid>
```

**ViewModel [QuestHTMLViewModel]**

```
public class QuestHTMLViewModel : Screen
{
}
```

**ShellView (Where the previous view is rendered)**

```
<xctk:BusyIndicator VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}">
    <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" />
</xctk:BusyIndicator>
```

**ShellViewModel (Where CefSharp view is set to ActiveItem)[Constructor Only]**

```
    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        QuestHTML = new QuestHTMLViewModel();
        ActiveItem = QuestHTML;
    }
```

**Initialization**

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
    base.OnStartup(e);
}
```

Comment: are you using Prism framework?

Comment: I'm using Caliburn Micro for MVVM.

Comment: Have you tried stripping out the mvvm framework,  just get the basics working? You can see a basic working example at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize and show the `Window` in `OnStartUp()` method:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
   MainWindow = new MainWindow();
   MainWindow.ShowDialog();
   base.OnStartup(e);
}
```

and do not forget to remove `StartupUri` property from `App.xaml`. `App.xaml` should look like this:

```
<Application x:Class="TestPlace.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: There's been a misunderstanding I think.  I've updated my original post.

Comment: @Jeff are you sure that your `viewmodel` is loaded and `viewmodel` is used as `DataContext` class for `View`?

Comment: Yes the `ViewModel` is loading.  If I change `cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser` to a regular `WebBrowser` it displays the HTML.  The issue with `WebBrowser` though is that it doesn't render my .css correctly.